# GCP serviceusage API returning 404s

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to use the GCP service usage API to get a list of enabled APIs for a project.

My Go code is as follows:

```
apiService, err := serviceusage.NewService(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error initializing the service usage API: %w", err)
}

apiList, err := apiService.Services.List(project.ProjectId).Do()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error getting list of enabled services for %s: %w", project.ProjectId, err)
}
```

I've confirmed that I have the necessary application default credentials because I can access other GCP APIs. I've also confirmed that I have the serviceusage.googleapis.com API enabled for my project.

However, I get a 404, as if this API endpoint is no longer in existence:

```
error getting list of enabled services for scratch-12345: googleapi: got HTTP response code 404 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  [...]
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/scratch-12345/services?alt=json&amp;prettyPrint=false</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I've checked that "scratch-12345" is the right project ID and is a project I own.

Comment: A clue: the curl examples in the GCP docs use a REST endpoint like `/v1/projects/<project id>/services` whereas it looks like the Golang client is using `/v1/<project id>/services`. Perhaps the Golang client for this API is just outdated? (https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#curl)

Answer (score 1):

For this API it turns out you need to identify projects by the string `"project/PROJECT_NUMBER"` rather than the project ID. The following lines fix the problem:

```
projNum := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%d", project.ProjectNumber)
apiList, err := apiService.Services.List(projNum).Do()
```